# When im trying to open terminal the terminal is totally blank there is nit even a durectory or $ appearing while opening the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, bashrc

When im trying to open terminal the terminal is totally blank there is nit even a durectory or $ appearing while opening the terminal?

What should i do now? Please guide me step by step

Comment: could be something in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`. Try Alt-F2 and type `gnome-terminal -- bash -x` and tell us the output (especially the last line).

Comment: Alternatively, post the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file since that is the most likely culprit. Have you made any changes to that file recently?